# Microsoft Word: keep a sequence of words safe from line breaks

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to mark a sequence of words so that line breaks won't separate them.

Can this be done? how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to insert **nonbreaking spaces** between the words you need to keep on the same line.

To create a nonbreaking space, first remove the regular space between the words. Then with your mousepointer pointer positioned between between the two words, hold down on the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys as you press the <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd>. The result is that the words remain together on the same line.

Comment: Darn you just beat me to it